# Fix 'Accept-Language' header for a CSOM request in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to fix the language of a PnP PowerShell request. Specifically, I'd like to extract site scripts from a web in a neutral language.

Here's what I tried :

```
$cnx = Connect-PnPOnline -ReturnConnection `
                         -Url https://somewhere.sharepoint.com/sites/overtherainbow `
                         -ClientId a165e590-a591-4897-cd27-929ccddb9908 `
                         -ClientSecret "supersecret"


Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $cnx.Context -EventName ExecutingWebRequest -Action {
    param(
        [object]$sender,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebRequestEventArgs]$args
    )

    [void] $args.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us")
    
}


Get-PnPSiteScriptFromList -Url https://somewhere.sharepoint.com/sites/overtherainbow/SitePages -Connection $cnx
```

However, the result isn't in english, but in the default site language.

Monitoring the network using Fiddler doesn't show the expected header at all.

How to fix that ? Is there an alternative to reach my goal ?

PS: if I try to execute the REST method using Insomnia, I get what I want to achieve. The header is present

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post. Helped me find a missing piece to something I was working on.

As for the question... the property is RequestHeaders on the WebRequestExecutor type itself.

```
[void] $args.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us")
```

Essentially the same thing here:

```
$Ctx.add_ExecutingWebRequest({
param($Source, $EventArgs)
$request  = $EventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders
$request.Add("Accept-Language","en-us")
})
```

Hope that helps, even if it's over a year old.